# Read Specific Excel Cell Data in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a column in my pandas data-frame where each row has a string with multiple line breaks. I am trying to use just the last 2 line breaks to create a new column. The cells have varying amounts of line breaks.

Is there a function that will allow for me to specifically pull the last 2 line breaks in excel?

Below is my failed attempt.

```
text= df['Column_Name'].str.rsplit('\r\n', 3)
```

Comment: Could you share ```df``` data? (Preferably in ```dict``` \ ```list``` format + what exactly do you mean the output to be? I suppose your excel is read to pandas, each row (delimited by line-break) will be different row in pandas, hence top 3 rows would be: ```df.iloc[:3]```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iḿ not sure what you exactly are looking for, but maybe this help:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_Name': ['line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5',
                                   'line 6\nline 7\nline 8']})
linebreaks = 3

df['linebreaks'] = ['\n'.join(x[1].to_list()) for x in\
                    df.Column_Name.str.split('\n', expand=False)\
                    .explode().groupby(level=0).tail(linebreaks).groupby(level=0)]

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                              Column_Name              linebreaks
0  line 1\nline 2\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5  line 3\nline 4\nline 5
1                  line 6\nline 7\nline 8  line 6\nline 7\nline 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this. I ended up using this: 

text1= df['Street Address'].str.strip()
text2= text1.str.rsplit('\r\n',2, expand=True)
df["1"]= text2[1] + "," + text2[2]

Answer (score 0):

Read each line in any way you want and then you can split it by break lines and use lineArray[-2:]

```
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    lineSplitted = line.split('\n')
    print(lineSplitted[-2:])
```